# How to solve error with java.lang.error with "mysecondclass.java:11"?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```java
package package1;

public class Mysecondclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\selenium servers files\\chromedriver.exe");
         WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
         driver.get("https://api.whitelion.in/api");
        
    }

}
```

The JAR file is not able to find webdriver as well as chromedriver error arise after running the code. The error is like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type
    ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type

    at javanew/package1.Mysecondclass.main(Mysecondclass.java:11)
```

I expected to run the code and provide me the error log of particular website and to resolve it so that website project can upload live.

Comment: Well that error means that your Java code (not Javascript) does not compile - you need to sort out the compilation problems.

Comment: I tried but after complete installation of jar files, the jar file get unresolved at the time of running the java code.

Comment: Your Java code is invalid: in `Mysecondclass.java`, line 11 there is a syntax error that prevents this part to be compiled. Maybe you just missed to add the import statement for `WebDriver`. It's hard to help without the code. So please show your code.

Comment: The code is added in the details of questions. Thank you all of you for helping me.

Comment: You mention Eclipse not finding jar files. Do you have the jars that include the the `webdriver` and `chromedriver` classes? You haven't imported them into the class shown above so is another class in your code referencing them? At a minimum you will need to import those classes into `Mysecondclass` and fix the Eclipse project setup so it can find the classes at compile and run time.

Comment: After `package package1;` the lines `import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;` and `import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;` are missing.